# Is "sense" perfectly natural here?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs

Woman: Would you like to hear about it?   (it=the woman's day.)

Man: ...Okay.

Woman: You sure? You don't have to.

Man: No, but I can **sense** you'd like to tell me about it.

Is **sense** perfectly natural here? Or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

"Sense" is perfectly natural here. It has a meaning very close to "feel emotionally" but with an added overtone of "rational" understanding. He is saying

> No, I don't actively want to, but I am pretty certain that you do want to, so let's do it.

Comment: How about "feel", could that be used as well?

Comment: Yes. It would mean just about the same thing though, to my ear, "sense" is a bit more tentative and intellectual than 'feel." When we get to very subtle shades of meaning, not everyone will agree.

Comment: Would it be more natural?

Comment: It depends what meaning you intend to convey. Both are perfectly natural here. I have explained what I think the very slight difference in meaning would be in this context. It is a common mistake to believe that frequency of use is more important than meaning. English has a huge vocabulary; you are free to use every word in it. The only true error is using a word that does not convey your intended meaning as exactly as possible.